# Copy and paste jpg/png to clipboard in android

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste, image

I would like to copy image from my application and would like to paste in SMS application(Now SMS would be converted to MMS). I am implementing on android OS version 4.0 .

I have done as per follows ,

- Created jpg image from the EditText using below code

  writeBitmapToSdcard(editCopy.getDrawingCache());
- Now I am copying this image(from sdcard) to the clipboad using ClipData class as shown below

> String file_path = "sdcard full path";
>   ClipData data = ClipData.newRawUri("image", Uri.parse(file_path));
>   ClipboardManager ClipMan = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
>   ClipMan.setPrimaryClip(data);

- Now when I am going to sms(native) application, and long press on MessageBox to create new message, and clicking on paste option, gives me only path of the image. It does not display image.

I would like to know that is it possible to copy and paste image ? And if possible, how could we do this ?

Comment: Is there anybody...Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with this modification on Android 4.1:

```
...
ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(Uri.parse(file_path));
ClipData data = new ClipData("label", new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, item);
...
```

Anyway, it still didn't paste image in SMS app.

I feel that most apps, including built-in ones, are not at this time ready for copy/paste of images on Clipboard.

Comment: Yes it might be. Also in native SMS application, we can attach any file but we can't copy. We can copy only text. I have found that to create such pasting application , we need to create our own application that will handle paste operation for the images.